# Make ActionResult Asynchronous To Increse Performance And elimate Flickering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parallel-processing, async-await, flicker

I want to make this Action Asynchronous,Can Anyone Help On this.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadAddressDetail(int? whId)
{
    try
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            GridData = wareHouseMasterService.LoadAddressGrid(GetCommonProperty(), whId ?? 0, DataManager.CustomerType, DataManager.CustomerTypeCode.WAREHOUSE.ToString()),
            Status = true
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { this.loggerService.Error(e); return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }
}
```

Since I am Using Three httpget Methods executed at one page load and the screen flickers Three Times.So I need parallel Processing.

Comment: Making the `ActionResult` asynchronous will not increase performance, nor will it eliminate flickering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for here. Making an action async is as simple as adding the `async` keyword and returning `Task<ActionResult>`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadAddressDetail(int? whId)
```

Of course, then, you must `await` something. The only thing I see that seems to do any work is `wareHouseMasterService.LoadAddressGrid`, but you've provided no details about what this does. Generally speaking, you would need to make this method async, as well, or add an async version of it. Then, you would simple do:

```
GridData = await wareHouseMasterService.LoadAddressGridAsync(...),
```

All that said, there's a big gotcha to keep in mind. Async, in the context of a web request, isn't the same thing as parallel processing, and it also does not make anything happen "faster". Additionally, there's a minor performance impact from using async, as there's overhead that goes along with that. In other words, simply making this action action async does not really in fact serve any other your mentioned goals.

The true reason to use async is to allow your web server to handle load more efficiently. When the thread handling the request is in a wait-state, async allows the thread to be returned to the pool to field other requests. Since there's a ceiling to the amount of threads a web server can spawn, and therefore the number of requests it can handle simultaneously, async gives you some extra head room when the server is under load. That's pretty much it, though.

That said, if you're trying all this out in development, using IIS Express, it's important to realize that IIS Express is *single-threaded*. In other words, requests are queued and handled serially, since raw performance is not a real factor in development. Therefore, in this situation, your three AJAX requests are being processed one at a time, rather than in parallel as they likely would be in full IIS, and that may be the source of what you're experiencing. Async *may* help here, but not necessarily. Regardless, it's only an issue in development.

Short of all that, you need to look at your JavaScript and ensure that you are doing things in an optimized way such that the AJAX requests are processed efficiently. There's also ways to minimize the flash of unstyled content issues apart from simply making everything happen quicker. However, since you've posted no code in this regard, there's not more that can be said.